# What could cause a record to appear in the MySQL binary log but not the original table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger, logs

I have a web application (CiviCRM) that has the option to enable binary logging, which I've done.  We use this software to record donations, including automatic recurring donations.  Our payment processor sends a POST request to a particular URL, which SHOULD create a new donation record in the db.  Instead, it's creating a record in the log table with `log_action` of `Insert`, but there's no corresponding record in the original table - and no `Delete` record in the log.

What circumstances might cause this?  Where should I begin troubleshooting?  There's no clustering/relaying - there are a handful of triggers that act on this record, which I'm eyeing suspiciously, but would appreciate input.

MySQL version is 5.5.44-0+deb7u1.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you lack the [**SUPER privilege (global permission)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super).

When you connect to MySQL, run `SHOW GRANTS;`

If you see more than one line, you do not have [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super).

What does having [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) give you ?

> The SUPER privilege enables an account to use CHANGE MASTER TO, KILL or mysqladmin kill to kill threads belonging to other accounts (you can always kill your own threads), PURGE BINARY LOGS, configuration changes using SET GLOBAL to modify global system variables, the mysqladmin debug command, enabling or disabling logging, performing updates even if the read_only system variable is enabled, starting and stopping replication on slave servers, specification of any account in the DEFINER attribute of stored programs and views, and enables you to connect (once) even if the connection limit controlled by the max_connections system variable is reached.
>
> To create or alter stored functions if binary logging is enabled, you may also need the SUPER privilege, as described in Section 20.7, “Binary Logging of Stored Programs”.

This also means you may only have database level grants for all users.

How can you tell ?

Login as root@localhost and run this

```
SELECT
    A.column_name GlobalPrivilege,
    IFNULL(B.column_name,'Not at DB Level') DBPrivilege
FROM
(SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user'
AND column_name LIKE '%priv') A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='db'
AND column_name LIKE '%priv') B
USING (column_name);
```

You should see something like this

```
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| GlobalPrivilege        | DBPrivilege           |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| Select_priv            | Select_priv           |
| Insert_priv            | Insert_priv           |
| Update_priv            | Update_priv           |
| Delete_priv            | Delete_priv           |
| Create_priv            | Create_priv           |
| Drop_priv              | Drop_priv             |
| Reload_priv            | Not at DB Level       |
| Shutdown_priv          | Not at DB Level       |
| Process_priv           | Not at DB Level       |
| File_priv              | Not at DB Level       |
| Grant_priv             | Grant_priv            |
| References_priv        | References_priv       |
| Index_priv             | Index_priv            |
| Alter_priv             | Alter_priv            |
| Show_db_priv           | Not at DB Level       |
| Super_priv             | Not at DB Level       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv  | Create_tmp_table_priv |
| Lock_tables_priv       | Lock_tables_priv      |
| Execute_priv           | Execute_priv          |
| Repl_slave_priv        | Not at DB Level       |
| Repl_client_priv       | Not at DB Level       |
| Create_view_priv       | Create_view_priv      |
| Show_view_priv         | Show_view_priv        |
| Create_routine_priv    | Create_routine_priv   |
| Alter_routine_priv     | Alter_routine_priv    |
| Create_user_priv       | Not at DB Level       |
| Event_priv             | Event_priv            |
| Trigger_priv           | Trigger_priv          |
| Create_tablespace_priv | Not at DB Level       |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

As shown, [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) does not exist for a DB Level user.

You can run this

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.db;
```

to see your DB Level users.

Please also look into your DB level user having the [TRIGGER privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger), which can allow a database level user to create, drop, or execute triggers.

Your real problem comes from Drupal's required settings for CiviCRM

- [Drupal.org : CiviCRM 4.2 and higher require more SQL privileges than past versions or binary logging disabled](https://www.drupal.org/node/1825018)
- [CiviCRM Community Forums : MySQL Triggers and binary logging](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=18962.msg85636#msg85636) suggests giving out the [TRIGGER privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger).

You can look into doing on of the following:

- make all users global users and give them [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) (not secure)
- give away the [TRIGGER privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger) to all DB users

  - `UPDATE mysql.db SET trigger_priv = 'Y';`
  - `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: This answer seems to be aimed at the opposite problem - a record created with no corresponding binary log.  This user has TRIGGER permission but not SUPER, for security reasons.  Does your answer respond to the scenario of a binary log with no corresponding record and I'm just not understanding?